# Labeling a point at which a perpendicular is dropped

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I saw the following code for drawing a triangle separated into two right triangles used in a demonstration of the Pythagorean Theorem.  What does the code `\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)` instruct TikZ to typeset?  How can I add "P" to the picture at the point that (dotted) line segment from C intersects line segment AB?  I guess that I use the command `\tkzLabelPoint`. What is the optional argument to position `P`? After I label this point, I guess that I can have TikZ draw a right angle at this intersection with a command like `\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,P,B)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)
\tkzGetPoint{B}

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}

\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,C,B)

\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](B,A)

\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,A){$b$}

\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](A,B)(C)
\tkzGetPoint{P}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](A,C,P)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](P,C,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](B,A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does the code "\tkzDefPointWithorthogonal normed,K=7" instruct TikZ to typeset

Let us say, you have this command:

```
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)
```

It instructs `tikz` to draw a perpendicaular to the line CA at C with the length of perpendicular line being K=7. From the manual, you have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\verb|\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=2](A,B)|

Here, $AB \perp AC$ and $K = 2$ means $AC = 2$

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\tkzInit[ymin=1,xmax=5,ymax=5] \tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,2){B}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=2](A,B)
\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right=3pt](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> How can I add "P" to the picture at the point that (dotted) line
>   segment from C intersects line segment AB? I guess that I use the
>   command "\tkzLabelPoint". What is the optional argument to position
>   "P"?

Your guess is correct. You can give regular position specifier that you use with `tikz` like `above`, `below`, `above right` etc as the optional arguments. 
so this is a possibility:

```
\tkzLabelPoint[below](P){$P$}  %% This added to put the label P below
```

> After I label this point, I guess that I can have TikZ draw a right
>   angle at this intersection with a command like
>   "\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,P,B)".

You guessed it right :-)

Now your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,4){C}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)
\tkzGetPoint{B}

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}

\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,C,B)

\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[green!60!black](B,A)

\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,A){$b$}

\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](A,B)(C)
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](P){$P$}  %% This added to put the label P below

\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](C,B,A)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=cyan,mark=|](A,C,P)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](P,C,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=orange,mark=||](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,P,B) %% This added
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't see the command "\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=blah]" in any manual for TikZ. Is there a manual at a website that you can suggest to explain this command?  What does "K" represent in this command? I see in the code that "\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=7](C,A)" precedes the command "\tkzGetPoint{B}". I am guessing that this code first plots points A and C, draws a line segment of length 7 from point C, and puts point B at the end. Why do you need "swap" in the command "\tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,C){$a$}" for labeling the length of line segment BC?

Comment: @user60254 you need the manual for [`tkz-euclide`](hhtp://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) which is a nice package built upon PGF/TikZ. Follow the link I provided and you'll find the manual for the package (in French) under the section "Documentation".

Comment: @user60254 See the manual of [tkz-euclide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Is there any documentation available in English? (Or Welsh, just to prove I don't insist on English. Just English seems more likely. Statistically. A manual in Breton would not be too bad as I could probably figure that out. French is hopeless.) [That is, I am hopeless at French. I don't mean French is hopeless at anything.]

Comment: @cfr Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[PointSymbol=none,RightAngleSize=.2,MarkAngle=90](9,5)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,90,0},CurveType=polygon,linecolor=ForestGreen](1,1){A}(3,4){C}([offset=6]{A}C){B}
    \pstProjection{A}{B}{C}[P]
    \pstRightAngle{B}{C}{A}
    \pstRightAngle{C}{P}{B} 
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=.7,Mark=MarkHashh,linecolor=Cyan}
    \pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{C}{}
    \pstMarkAngle{P}{C}{B}{}
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=.9,Mark=MarkHash,linecolor=Magenta}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{C}{P}{}
    \pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{P}{}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=Maroon](C)(P)    
    \psset{linestyle=none,shortput=nab}
    \pcline(A)(B)_{$c$}
    \pcline(C)(B)^{$a$}
    \pcline(A)(C)^{$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]